# Error while making network call - Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0."

Tags: ios, json, xcode, nsurlsession

**Background:**

This code basically calls an API(details given below) with the parameters(also stated below)- The error seems to happen while parsing/obtaining the jsonResponse.

**What I've tried so far:**

I read online that this happens when you pass in wrong format or the wrong parameters - I have attached the details of the API below and it matches the ones that are passed. What seems to be going wrong?

**Current Network Call Implementation:**

```
   public static func lockdownSafe(with safeID: String, action: LockdownState, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> ()) {
        let json = ["safeID": safeID, "current_safe_lockdown_status": action.rawValue]
        guard let requestURL = URL(string: baseURL + paths.lockdownSafe) else {
            return
        }
        print("JSON",json)
        var request = URLRequest(url: requestURL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: [])
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue( "Bearer 12345", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
        print(request)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let data = data {
                completion(nil)
                do{
                    let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:
                        data, options: .allowFragments)
                    print("Response result is",jsonResponse) //Response result
                    
                } catch let parsingError {
                    print("Error:", parsingError)
                }
            } else if let error = error {
                completion(error)
            }
        }
        
        task.resume()
    
    }
```

**API Details:**

LockDown

```
{ 
    "safeID": "safe document ID", (string)
    "current_safe_lockdown_status": "enable/disable" (string)
}

[Mobile > Firebase] - ( [POST] https://projectURL/safe/lockdown/lockdown ) 
Looks for mac_address in “Safes” collection based on “SafeID”
[Firebase > AWS > safeOS] Forwards the request to safeOS with “safeID”.
safeOS sets the safe to LOCKDOWN mode and sends a response to firebase.
[safeOS >AWS > Firebase]-([POST] https://projectURL/safe/lockdown/setlockdown )

{ 
    "safeID": "safe document ID", (string)
    "current_safe_lockdown_status": "enable/disable" (string)
}
```

**Error Details:**

```
JSON ["safeID": "aprTHvKxWIsgPPFKE6Z9", "current_safe_lockdown_status": "enable"]
https://silo-test.firebaseapp.com/safe/lockdown/lockdown
Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
```

You can see the JSON and the API URL which I've printed out - and that they match the definition^
What am I missing?

Comment: `Invalid value around character 0` means the received data is not JSON. Create a string from `data` and `print` it. And `allowFragments` is pointless if the expected type is array or dictionary.

Comment: If I remove allowFragments, I get "UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."

Comment: Yes but this is not the point. As I said *the received data is not JSON* at all.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more on how I can make the data JSON?

Comment: It's a server communication issue. Insert `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)` after the `completion(nil)` line and read what the server returns.

Comment: It prints out - Error. Could not handle the request
Also I tried printing out the response and the status code is 500